# .htaccess on host gator is not removing .php extension and adding trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have recently uploaded my new website to hostgator.

I am trying to remove .php extension and add a trailing slash to all my urls.

For example

website.com/about.php should change to website.com/about/

I have the htaccess code that has worked for other websites on different hosts, but when i tried it for this website on hostgator it doesnt work.

This is the code I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]


# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.co.uk/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Currently I now have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Hostgator added this htaccess for me which basically redirects http requests to https and removes http://www.website.co.uk and www.website.co.uk to website.co.uk

What can I do to remove .php extension and force trailing slash?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the code in your site root .htaccess with this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ https://%1/$1/ [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,NE,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# To internally rewrite /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser or after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Hello, this did work, however, it also did too many redirects, so after it loaded my page correctly if i look in web inspecter, it loads my files again which look like this : website.com/web-page.php.php.php.php.php.php etc

Comment: Try my updated rules in a browser. If you still get redirect look then test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: I just get a punch of 301 redirects, even the images have added .php.php.php.php etc

Comment: Try my updated rules again after clearing browser cache and restart.

Comment: This is what i now get, again it does work and adds the trailing slash, however a few files it trys to add the slash are incorrect, Also it lets me go to website.com// instead of just website.com - https://ibb.co/YXWmxs5

Answer (score 0):

For starters, depending on your hosting environment you may need to add the following to the beginning of your htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews is on the server will do implicit filename matching. So if you request page/ it could interpret that as page.php. Use the option above to disable MultiViews and see if that helps.

Comment: Is the server actually hosting .php files? Are you just trying to have the url in the address bar not show php, even though the user is typing in php and there is php in the backend?

Comment: You can also view hostgator's default htaccess files here: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/default-files-htaccess-and-php-ini